# How to convert a List of Lists to a DataFrame in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark and Scala, and was experimenting in the spark REPL.

When I try to convert a List to a DataFrame, it works as follows:

```
val convertedDf = Seq(1,2,3,4).toDF("Field1")
```

However, when I try to convert a list of lists to a DataFrame with two columns (field1, field2), it fails with

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of
>   columns doesn't match

error message:

```
val twoColumnDf =Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4,5), Seq(5,4,3,2,3)).toDF("Field1", (Field2))
```

How to convert such a List of Lists to a DataFrame in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are *seeking ways to have each elements of each sequence in each row of respective columns* then following are the options for you

## zip

`zip` both sequences and then apply `toDF` as

```
val twoColumnDf =Seq(1,2,3,4,5).zip(Seq(5,4,3,2,3)).toDF("Field1", "Field2")
```

which should give you `twoColumnDf` as

```
+------+------+
|Field1|Field2|
+------+------+
|1     |5     |
|2     |4     |
|3     |3     |
|4     |2     |
|5     |3     |
+------+------+
```

## zipped

Another better way is to use zipped as

```
val threeColumnDf = (Seq(1,2,3,4,5), Seq(5,4,3,2,3), Seq(10,10,10,12,14)).zipped.toList.toDF("Field1", "Field2", "field3")
```

which should give you

```
+------+------+------+
|Field1|Field2|field3|
+------+------+------+
|1     |5     |10    |
|2     |4     |10    |
|3     |3     |10    |
|4     |2     |12    |
|5     |3     |14    |
+------+------+------+
```

But `zipped` works only for *maximum three sequeces* Thanks for pointing that out @Shaido

**Note: the number of rows is determined by the shortest sequence present**

## transpose

`Tanspose` combines all sequences as `zip` and `zipped` does but returns list instead of tuples so a little hacking is needed as

```
Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4,5), Seq(5,4,3,2,3)).transpose.map{case List(a,b) => (a, b)}.toDF("Field1", "Field2")
+------+------+
|Field1|Field2|
+------+------+
|1     |5     |
|2     |4     |
|3     |3     |
|4     |2     |
|5     |3     |
+------+------+
```

and

```
Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4,5), Seq(5,4,3,2,3), Seq(10,10,10,12,14)).transpose.map{case List(a,b,c) => (a, b, c)}.toDF("Field1", "Field2", "Field3")
+------+------+------+
|Field1|Field2|Field3|
+------+------+------+
|1     |5     |10    |
|2     |4     |10    |
|3     |3     |10    |
|4     |2     |12    |
|5     |3     |14    |
+------+------+------+
```

and so on ...

**Note: transpose requires all sequences to be of same length**

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: what if I want to have 3 Seqs and 3 Columns? `eq(1,2,3,4,5).zip(Seq(5,4,3,2,3)).zip(Seq(10,10,10,12,14)).toDF("Field1", "Field2", "Field3")` gives an exception.

Comment: @user3243499: Or you can write it as a Seq of tuples directly: `Seq((1,5,10), (2,4,10), (3,3,10), (4,2,12), (5,3,14)).toDF("Field1", "Field2", "Field3")` which would be easier in some situations.

Comment: @Shaido thanks for point out. transpose is the right solution I guess :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Yes, that one looks more useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, each element is considered to be a Row of the dataFrame.
If you want each of the Seqs to be a different column you need to group them inside a Tuple:

```
val twoColumnDf =Seq((Seq(1,2,3,4,5), Seq(5,4,3,2,3))).toDF("Field1", "Field2")


twoColumnDf.show
+---------------+---------------+
|         Field1|         Field2|
+---------------+---------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[5, 4, 3, 2, 3]|
+---------------+---------------+
```